# Comparing date and month in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I have the following code that gets a date from a timestamp in the DB and then I compare it with specific dates and accordignly set a variable to some value:

```
    $leavedate=$this->leavedate;
    $leavestamp=strtotime($leavedate[0]['LoppumisPvm']);
    $leave=date('d M',$leavestamp);
    echo "the leave is: ".$leave; //this one prints: 12 Apr

        $leavequarter="";
       if(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jan') && strtotime(($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jan'))){$leavequarter=1;}
       elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Apr') && strtotime(($leave)<= strtotime('15 Apr'))){$leavequarter=2;}
       elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jul') && strtotime(($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jul'))){$leavequarter=3;}
       elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Oct') && strtotime(($leave)<= strtotime('15 Oct'))){$leavequarter=4;}


    echo $leavequarter;
```

The first echo works and I get something like `12 Apr` which basically should fit in the second `if` statement, however, it the 2nd echo does not print anything and even if I put something like `echo "test`" in those if statements none gets executed.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @AdamD, thanks but no.. that had no effect.

Comment: @AdamD [`elseif`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php): "Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting your code wrongly:

```
elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Apr') && strtotime(($leave)<= strtotime('15 Apr')))
```

It should be:

```
elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Apr') && strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Apr'))
                                                           ^                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax mistake the third strtotime got double (( covering the how second state

```
   if(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jan') && strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jan')){$leavequarter=1;}
   elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Apr') && strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Apr')){$leavequarter=2;}
   elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jul') && strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jul')){$leavequarter=3;}
   elseif(strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Oct') && strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Oct')){$leavequarter=4;}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i would not do it all with strtotime. this is resource consuming and depends on locales.

better to use the date function.

```
$leavedate = $this->leavedate;
$leavestamp = strtotime($leavedate[0]['LoppumisPvm']);
$leave = date('d M', $leavestamp);
echo "the leave is: " . $leave; //this one prints: 12 Apr

$leavequarter = "";
if (date('m', $leavestamp) == 1 && date('d', $leavestamp) >= 1 && date('d', $leavestamp) <= 15)
{
    $leavequarter = 1;
}
elseif (date('m', $leavestamp) == 4 && date('d', $leavestamp) >= 1 && date('d', $leavestamp) <= 15)
{
    $leavequarter = 2;
}
elseif (date('m', $leavestamp) == 7 && date('d', $leavestamp) >= 1 && date('d', $leavestamp) <= 15)
{
    $leavequarter = 3;
}
elseif (date('m', $leavestamp) == 10 && date('d', $leavestamp) >= 1 && date('d', $leavestamp) <= 15)
{
    $leavequarter = 4;
}


echo $leavequarter;
```

but what are you trying to do? i think you want to get the quarter of the year, but this only gives results for 1st januari to 15th of januari and same for april, july and october.

honestly i think this is what you want:

```
$leavedate = $this->leavedate;
$leavestamp = strtotime($leavedate[0]['LoppumisPvm']);
$leave = date('d M', $leavestamp);
echo "the leave is: " . $leave; //this one prints: 12 Apr

$leavequarter = (int) ((date('m', $leavestamp) - 1) / 3) + 1;
echo $leavequarter;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
if((strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jan')) && (strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jan'))){$leavequarter=1;}
    elseif((strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Apr')) && (strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Apr'))){$leavequarter=2;}
    elseif((strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Jul')) && (strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Jul'))){$leavequarter=3;}
    elseif((strtotime($leave)>= strtotime('01 Oct')) && (strtotime($leave)<= strtotime('15 Oct'))){$leavequarter=4;}   
echo $leavequarter;
```